# Generate Javascript intellisense file for a .NET Class

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I have a .net control which is intended for use as an ActiveX control in web pages, instantiated thus:

```
<object id="TheControl" name="TheControl" classid="clsid:012937D0-E1D8-4a80-A17F-DEADBEEFF00D"></object>
```

Is there a way to take the XML documentation generated by Visual Studio for `TheControl` and transform it into a `.js` file that Visual Studio could then consume to provide intellisense for an instance of the control in a page?

Comment: May I recommend againts ActiveX controls. I can see the use in not upgrading them in legacy projects but if your using VS2010 it's not a legacy project. It's best not to create _new_ ActiveX controls so we can move forward with web standards. Most likely there is a HTML5 equivelant.

Comment: @Raynos, you can recommend all you want, but unless HTML5 allows me to open a socket connection back to one of our servers and thus trigger various telephony actions, via a *well defined API exposed by the control*, you'll be out of luck! =) Sweeping statements like "*It's best not to create new ActiveX controls so we can move forward with web standards.*" seldom take into account reality ;-) (For example, how would you write an online virus scanner using HTML5?)

Comment: @Rob If by socket you mean TCP socket you can look at `socket.io` although that doesn't integrate all too well into the `.NET` back end. In an ideal world we wouldn't have to make these kind of applications in a website but instead through a desktop applications or maybe something like Flash or Silverlight which is (only) slightly more standard then ActiveX. I prefer to not take "reality" into account until absolutely necessary. But if we stop writing ActiveX controls IE6 might just die and our lives become better! In reality ActiveX is probably the best option for you.

Comment: @Raynos - "But if we stop writing ActiveX controls IE6 might just die", was there really a need to conflate two entirely unrelated things? **ActiveX != IE6**. That said, this thread of comments isn't getting me any closer to an answer so I'll stop now :)

Comment: @Rob actually on topic there may be a good and well documented WebSocket abstraction geared at .NET with IE8+ support.

Comment: @Raynos - take it from me, it's not an acceptable solution :) The .net control is used in other, non-web applications. Implementing the same API twice is a non-starter. It's *not* going to change so it's not going to get me *any* closer to answering my question (*how do I generate javascript intellisense from Visual Studio .XML files that it generates from code comments*). :)

Comment: @Rob I don't actually know that. Hey you can always write a parser for XML -> .vsdoc, that would waste a couple of days. Althought it looks like connecting the .vsdoc file to your control in VS2010 is the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would either have to use .NET Reflection to get a list of all properties and methods, or write an XML parser tool to get the same list, and then generate .JS source code from it.

I think both of these would take about the same effort to write, but the Reflection approach can also be used with just the ActiveX file- if you don't have Visual Studio handy to generate the documentation XML.

If all you want is an "empty shell" .JS file for the properties and methods, then the code in this article should provide a good basis:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Reflection.aspx